# Getting into root mode via an App for a device that is not rooted

Tags: android, permissions, root

I'm trying to read the MSR information from an android device with userDebug build , and it requires root permission. I have tried adding :**process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");** and when i debugged the program ,the variable process is getting initialized with NULL. And I have made some function call to read the MSR value by specifying its path /dev/msr*,and when i run the program the log window shows Permission denied. So is there any way to get into root permission via an app without having a rooted android device?

Answer (score 3):

> So is there any way to get into root permission via an app without having a rooted android device?

By definition, no.

Comment: But my device is having a Userdebug Build. And by definition of a userdebug build it does have root permission, then why is my app still prompting Permission denied issues while accessing device files like /dev/msr* from an android app???

Answer (score 0):

> process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

`su` command is to run the shell commands in Super user mode.

If the device is rooted, this command causes SuperUser to show a dialog, which lets you either Allow or Block it from root access.

> So is there any way to get into root permission via an app without
>   having a rooted android device?

There is *no official way* to do this. If your app needs SuperUser access, then you can build one click root method like rooting apps and can ask the user to root first.

Comment: I guess the ***su*** command is only found on ***rooted*** devices.

Comment: Thank you Jyoti,but my device is having a Userdebug Build. And by definition of a userdebug build it does have root permission, then why is my app still prompting Permission denied issues while accessing device files like /dev/msr*???

Comment: Userdebug Build has root permission by which definition?

Comment: @JyotiJK But the OP asked: `Getting into root mode via an App for a device that is not rooted`